# Code splitting in React causes API calls to be executed multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am building a web application using React. I have used React Lazy with Webpack for code splitting but there is one issue that I have encountered. If I am on page A and I visit another screen (B) and now I re-visit the last screen (A) the screen is loaded again and the API calls in the useEffect hook of the component (A) is executed again.

My app does not have data that will constantly change so I dont want to call it again and again. What I concluded was that when the users visits another screen React unmounts the previous component and when the user visits again it mounts the component and executes the useEffect hook.

So, there are unnecessary API calls that I want to avoid. I know that I can cache my API calls but that feels like a workaround. Is there a better alternative to API caching or have I made some mistake in my code?

My app.js file where code splitting is implemented:

```js
const LoginContainer = lazy(()=> import('./Container/StudentDashboard.container'));
```

My StudentDashboard.container.js file:

```js
const StudentDashboard = ()=>{
  useEffect(()=>{
    (async()=>{
      const data = await fetch({...}) # this API call is executed every time user visits the screen
     })
  },[])
}
```

Comment: Try sending an empty array of dependencies to useEffect

Comment: @ludwiguer It has an empty array of dependencies

Comment: What makes you think this is related to code-splitting? Does it behave the same without using lazy components? If your problem is that a component is unmounting and remounting, then you will need to find a way to keep the state outside of the component, such that it won't be lost when the component unmounts. There isn't enough information here to know how the two components are composed, why `StudentDashboard` might be unmounting, and where that state should be kept.

Comment: In cases of code being executed multiple times, I always use `console.log` to understand where the double-subscription happens. Try to put a `console.log` at the place where you send the api-call, one at the place where the method is subscribed to, and so on...

Comment: @rfestag without lazy components the screen is never unmounted and the api calls is not executed multiple times

Comment: @Pieterjan I have tried that and the conclusion I can to was that the components are being unmounted and mounted again when the user visits the screen again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a wrapper component where you fetch the data once. Then store this data in `ReactContext` and use the context in your screen components.

Here is the solution:

1. Create context for storing data

```
// DataProvider.js
const DataContext = React.createContext(null);

const useData = () => React.useContext(DataContext); // create custom hook to use data on different screens

const DataProvider = ({ children }) => (
  <DataContext.Provider value={React.useState(null)}>
    {children}
  </DataContext.Provider>
);
```

2. Create wrapper component to fetch and store data in the context

```
// DataResolver.js
function DataResolver({children}) {
  const [storedData, setStoredData] = useData(); // custom hook created in DataProvider.js

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAndStoreData = async () => {
      const data = await fetch({...});
      setStoredData(data);
    };

    if (!storedData) { // OR any your custom condition
      fetchAndStoreData();
    }
  },[]);

  return children;
}
```

3. Use wrapper component in your app component or the component which wraps your navigation screens

```
// App.js
function App() {
  return (
    <DataProvider>
      <DataResolver>
        {/* Your views or routing logic */}
        <View>...</View>
      </DataResolver>
    </DataProvider>
  );
}
```

4. Finally use the context in your screen component

```
// StudentDashboard.js
const StudentDashboard = ()=>{
  const [data] = useData(); // using custom hook you created in DataProvider.js
  ...
}
```

Comment: I really liked this approach but I think that I can create the data resolver function in the context itself and store the data there itself

Comment: @RamPandey not sure if I understood you well, The proposed way actually is storing data in the context. It just has to be fetched somewhere so DataResolver component serves this purpose. Note that you cant fetch in App component and pass data to context because App is not wrapped with DataProvider